# Query parameters with Impala ODBC driver

Tags: c#, odbc, impala

I'm using the Impala ODBC driver provided by Cloudera. I can't seem to use query parameters correctly.
For instance:

```
OdbcCommand command = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE test VALUES(?, ?)";
command.Parameters.Add("key", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "csharp";
command.Parameters.Add("val", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "test";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

throws the following exception.

> {"ERROR [HY000] [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a
>   query in Impala: [HY000] : AnalysisException: Syntax error in line
>   1:\nINSERT INTO TABLE test VALUES(?, ?)\n
>   ^\nEncountered: Unexpected character\nExpected: CASE, CAST, EXISTS,
>   FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER\n\nCAUSED
>   BY: Exception: Syntax error\n"}

Which should manage query parameters (and replacement of ? by values), ODBC library or the driver ? It seems to be the driver and in this case, it's not implemented... And it's a shame because I cannot use prepared statement.

Does somebody know a way to use query parameters with the Impala ODBC driver?

Comment: I found that I needed to avoid a trailing semicolon.   In your example, `"command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE test VALUES(?, ?)";` is correct but `command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE test VALUES(?, ?);";` would give me the same error you got.  This isn't your problem, but thought it might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT INTO TABLE` is Impala specific syntax. To use Impala ODBC to do INSERT with parameters you need the SQL 92 syntax which is `INSERT INTO <table name> ...`

Can you try the following syntax and see if it help?

`INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?)`

Comment: It works with INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?). However, it does not work with INSERT INTO test(col1, col2) VALUES(?, ?) but i will be sufficient. Thanks