# Laravel / IMPALA: How to do parameterized query?

Tags: php, laravel, odbc, laravel-7, impala

Ive got `laravel 7x` and `impala/kudu` (provided by `cloudera`). Ive got the `ODBC` connection which connects fine and if you run raw sql non-parameterised queries it works fine.

However I cant get the parameterised query working.

The Following works:

```
DB::connection('impala')->statement("insert into test1 values(4, 'zz')");
```

The following doesnt work:

```
DB::connection('impala')->statement('insert INTO test1 values(?, ?) ', [4, 'zz']);
DB::connection('impala')->insert('insert INTO test1 values(?, ?) ', [4, 'zz']);
```

The error I get is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 110 [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [HY000] : ParseException: Syntax error in line 1: INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(?, ?) ^
Encountered: Unexpected character. Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, LEFT, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, RIGHT, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER 
CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error (SQLExecute[110] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:260) (SQL: INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(4, 'zz') )
```

As you can see here someone already had same issue but it was in C# but that didnt work for me:
[Query parameters with Impala ODBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093083/query-parameters-with-impala-odbc-driver)

---

Also note, the query builder doesnt work with this connection / driver. So only way is to use raw queries

Comment: use `::insert` if you want to take up arguments instead

Comment: already tried it, doesnt work either